# What does this script actually do?

Tags: android, linux, curl, command, coordinates

I want to know what this script actually does. This is basically for **android mobile coordinate finder**

```
sudo curl -1 -s -k -x 'post' -H 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/LRX22C)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-   urlencoded' \
'http://mobile.maps.yandex.net/cellid_location/?clid=1866854&lac=-1&cellid=-1&operatorid=null&countrycode=null&signalstrength=-1&wifinetworks=xxxxxxxxxxxx:-65&app=ymetro'
```

and

```
Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U;Android 5.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/LRX22C)
```

this is that mobile version and detail, that i have to add all the time when i run.

I am trying my android MAC address, but it will not give any output on terminal.

Please suggest me some reasonable answer what this actually dose.

Comment: You're not very clear about what you are looking for. Please add some context. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This command looks like it goes to the internet to retrieve information from a site. It could indeed be coordinates of some device.

- `sudo` gains extended rights on your OS to perform any action
- `curl` is a command to retrieve data from Internet; here it performs a `post`, and gives `User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/LRX22C)' and  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as headers ( `-H`  option);  the http `POST` is performed to URL `http://mobile.maps.yandex.net/cellid_location/?clid=1866854&lac=-1&cellid=-1&operatorid=null&countrycode=null&signalstrength=-1&wifinetworks=xxxxxxxxxxxx:-65&app=ymetro`

You should see the answer as a file that should appear in the current directory, with the content of the server's answer.

To know more about what `curl` does, you can look [e.g. here](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/curl.1.html).